# Accessing a property from a ^block causes silly behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, block, asiformdatarequest

I've ran into some issues using ^blocks in Objective-C. I'm trying to set an instance variable from within a block - I've read through some Apple documentation on the topic, and I feel I have tried everything.

```
@interface MyClass
{
    // I have tried all possible combinations using __weak, __strong and __block.
    __weak __block NSMutableArray *filenames;
}

// *.m
static ASIFormDataRequest *g_request = nil;

@implementation MyClass
-(void) funnymethod
{
    filenames = [NSMutableArray array];
    [filenames addObject:@"This is a string."];
    NSLog(@"%@", filenames);

    g_request = [InitializerClass initializeRequest];
    [g_request setCompletionBlock:^
    {
        filenames = [NSMutableArray array];
        [filenames addObject:@"This is another string."];
        NSLog(@"%@", filenames);
    }];

    [g_object startASynchronous];
}
@end
```

The code above gives the following output:
    ( "This is a string." )
    (null)

That sucks. So, I've tried different combinations of __weak, __strong and __block - and anything else gives the following output:
    ( "This is a string." )
    ( "This is another string." )
BUT! There's a massive but. The completion block is never exited. The activity indicator in the top bar indicating an open connection keeps spinning, and the screen becomes unresponsive.

How can I set the filenames-object from within the block successfully? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if your completion block is totally empty? I think the problem with the ASIFormDataRequest not finishing has nothing to do with what you're doing in this block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What the qualifiers do:**

`__block` this qualifier allows a closure to modify the value stored in the given variable.

`__weak` is a reference to an object that *does not* prevent the object from being de-allocated.

`__strong` is a reference to an object that *does* prevent the object from being de-allocated.

**What you need to do:**

`__weak` doesn't do what you want because it doesn't prevent your array from being de-allocated after the current scope ends.  Since you are making an async call, there is nothing preventing the run-time from reclaiming the memory used by the array before your block is executed.

`__strong` will retain the object past the end of the current scope.  This is what you want.

`__block` will allow your block to modify the specified variable, however this isn't needed when referencing an instance variable since `self` will be automatically retained.

> In a reference-counted environment, by default when you reference an
>   Objective-C object within a block, it is retained. This is true even
>   if you simply reference an instance variable of the object. Object
>   variables marked with the __block storage type modifier, however, are
>   not retained.
>
> Note: In a garbage-collected environment, if you apply both __weak and
>   __block modifiers to a variable, then the block will not ensure that it is kept alive. If you use a block within the implementation of a
>   method, the rules for memory management of object instance variables
>   are more subtle:
>
> **If you access an instance variable by reference, self is retained;**

I think your problem lies here (relevant portions in **bold**):

> **You can specify that an imported variable be mutable—that is, read-write— by applying the __block storage type modifier.** __block storage is similar to, but mutually exclusive of, the register, auto, and static storage types for local variables.
>
> __block variables live in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or 
>   created within the variable’s lexical scope. Thus, the storage will 
>   survive the destruction of the stack frame if any copies of the blocks 
>   declared within the frame survive beyond the end of the frame (for 
>   example, by being enqueued somewhere for later execution). Multiple 
>   blocks in a given lexical scope can simultaneously use a shared 
>   variable.
>
> As an optimization, block storage starts out on the stack—just like 
>   blocks themselves do. If the block is copied using Block_copy (or in 
>   Objective-C when the block is sent a copy), variables are copied to 
>   the heap. Thus, the address of a __block variable can change over 
>   time.
>
> **There are two further restrictions on __block variables: they cannot 
>   be variable length arrays**, and cannot be structures that contain C99 
>   variable-length arrays.

Instead of an `NSMutableArray`, try using a plain `NSArray` using

`+ (id)arrayWithObject:(id)anObject`.

Comment: "Variable length array" in [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1) doesn't mean "NSMutableArray", it means ["C99 variable length array"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).  You're allowed to have a `__block NSMutableArray*`. (It might not make sense here, but it is allowed.)

Comment: You don't need `__block` to change the ivar, either. Accesses to ivars go through an implicit `self` variable, which is copied by the block. Effectively the block does `self->fileNames = newValue`.

Comment: I have to use NSArray instead of NSMutableArray. Never even strafed my mind!

Thank you so much for the informative post - appreciate it a lot! Made my day! :D

Comment: @AdmiralPimms If this fixes your problem, then please mark it as the answer.  So that other people who see the question know this fixed your issue.